# Appv 5 MSAccess database is read only

Tags: appv

I am currently trying to sequence an MSAccess mdb but the first thing that the application does is remove linked tables and reconnect them.  When it tries to do this I get an error saying that the database is read only.  I have shared the folder and given 'Everyone' full permissions to the mdb whilst sequencing. 
Is there a way that it can update the application after it has been virtualized?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know It's late to answer this question now, but this may help other people.
so the error message is clearly saying that the function 'gfcnRemoveAttachments' is trying to reconnect the linked-tables.
Si If you have access to the VBA code ,I think you should modify this function in way that not to re-link these tables.